# All elements with attribute class not containing "disabled"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few buttons which are generated programatically:

```
<button id="btn_b1" type="button" class="btn btn_default disabled">Disabled Button</button>
<button id="btn_b2" type="button" class="btn btn_default">Button</button>
```

The following code

```
$("button[id^='btn_b'][class~='disabled']")
```

selects `<button>` elements with an `id` attribute value containing the string `btn_b` and `class` attribute value contains `disabled`.

What I want to select are

`<button>` elements with an `id` attribute value containing the string `btn_b` and `class` attribute value does **not** contain `disabled`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`:not()` pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anot).

```
$("button[id^='btn_b']:not(.disabled)")
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method:

```
$("button[id^='btn_b']").not('.disabled');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$("button[id^='btn_b']:not(.disabled)")
```